# how can create specific folder when install setup file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, sql-server-express, setup-project

I want to make setup for my project and i have one folder "Resource"
in this path `..\bin\Debug`.now how can i make setup file ,that when
i install setup "Resource" folder with it's files become created in the
install folder ?
my database is sqlexpress for my database file what
should i do?it's folder is App_Data in `..\bin\Debug` path.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a certain installer technology that you were planning to use, or are you looking for advice on which one is best?

Comment: @Adkins:dose my question clear?i don't know how to make setup that it can create Resource folder in the install folder,when i install setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be creating more than just this one setup I would recommend looking into the [WiX Toolkit](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  It is an XML based toolkit that will let you create your MSI's with an amazing amount of customization.  Placing the folders that you need where you need them is no problem at all.  I think that might just be what you are looking for.  Also the link that I included has a link to a really great tutorial that would help you get started.